# Countdown time from Label HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I need to create a timer count down from value on Lable

```
time_left.Text = needtime.ToString()
```

sorry I am very beginner at Javascript but didn't work with me I think because the label is a string but I don't know how to convert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById("time_left").innerHTML;
    if (seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("time_left").innerHTML = seconds - 1;
        setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
```

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: hi my tried is very bad because i don't have any experience in JS

Comment: There are lots of countdown scripts all over the internet. Suggest you try implementing one that is well documented for you. Expecting someone here to write one for you is not how the site works

Comment: thanks for your reply, my problem here is how can get  result = 8:00:00 - totalHours = resulttime i know this wrong way to learn

Comment: @charlietfl here is my code

Comment: `how can get result = 8:00:00 - totalHours` ? results in what format? Seconds?

Comment: hh:mm:ss then I want make count down from it

Comment: @EbramShehata I personally would create a variable that holds the total seconds from when the timer starts to when the timer ends, and display a formatted version of that. It's probably too complicated to have hours, minutes, and seconds, starting at 24, 60, and 60, decrementing seconds then minutes, etc... just stick with seconds. You can use modulo (%) to get the remainder of division;
```hours = totalSeconds/60/24;
minutes = totalSeconds/60%24;
seconds = totalSeconds%60;
```

Something like that. I haven't used Java in a while so that code might not work, but you should get the gist.